# sending free messages to employee phones from Java application

Tags: java, android, messaging

We would like to be able to send instant messages to our employees from a Java application. Most of them have a phone with a data plan. Is there a free and easy way to do this?

I investigated using whatsapp, which most employees have installed, but it has no official API and it seems that a recent change also disabled the possibility to use the unofficial API's.

Perhaps there are whatsapp alternatives that provide an API?

Or is the only way to use mail or create my own android + iPhone apps to do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tropo API to send java messages.
Further details can be found below:-

https://www.tropo.com/2011/05/sending-outbound-sms-with-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysms.com API to send free messages. https://api.mysms.com

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try Whatsapp Web Automated with Selenium framework

The following links can be helpfull:

1. https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng
2. https://github.com/mukulhase/WebWhatsapp-Wrapper

Not all companies provide APIs, whatsapp doesnt want its customers to be bombarded with hoards of messages, that's why they arent giving any APIs

But the above links are a few work arounds. Proceed with caution.. If you send unusually high amount of messages you may get blocked